# OKHTTP RequestBody error cannot access ByteString

Tags: android, json, okhttp

I am trying to use OkHttpClient to post json data from Android to my server.

My code:

public static final MediaType JSON
            = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8");

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

private String post(String url, String json) throws IOException {
    RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, json);
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(url)
            .post(body)
            .build();
    Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
    return response.body().string();
}
```

Build error occurs here: `RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, json);`

Error: Error:(65, 39) error: cannot access ByteString
class file for okio.ByteString not found

I have copied the downloaded jar file from OkHttp (it's 3.0.1) to libs folder. Am I missing anything? What is causing the error?

Comment: After copying the jar file inside libs folder did you tell Android Studio to include it as library?

Answer (score 2):

I was having same issue `okio.ByteString not found`. I found a [github](https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/1685) issue.

its a separate package we need to include by our self.

You can find the latest [jar here](https://search.maven.org/remote_content?g=com.squareup.okio&a=okio&v=LATEST)